# How to Sketch the Charge density?

Tags: electromagnetism

There is a question in the [MIT course](http://web.mit.edu/course/8/8.07/8.07_99/2.html) where they ask to find the charge destiny  for the electric field $\vec{E} = A  \frac{e^{-br}}{ r} \hat{r}$

The charge density I have got using the Maxwell's equation is:

$$\rho= - \frac{\epsilon_0 Ab e^{-br}}{ r^2} + 4 \pi \epsilon_0 A\delta(r)$$

They asked to find the charge density with respect to the r. How to get that?

What I find the charge density at the center (r= o) is zero. and also for  other value of r, as the distance increases we get  exponentially  decay because ($\delta$ is zero for other values of r). Am i explaining it in proper way?

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is incorrect.

You need to use $\nabla\cdot\vec E=\dfrac{\rho}{\epsilon_o}$ which becomes $\dfrac{1}{r^2}\dfrac{d}{dr}\left( r^2E(r)\right)=\dfrac{\rho(r)}{\epsilon_o}$ in your example.